# facebook cannot crawl website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-crawler

i have a website [website](http://skytrek.co.il)

when trying to share a blog post i facebook decided not to show the `og:` tags rather then show an automated selection.
[image]

furthermore when trying to post a message using facebook comment i get a warning:
"http://skytrek.co.il/he/company/blog/view/?ContentiD=443 cannot be crawled by Facebook's servers."
[image]

trying to fetch new scrape information using facebook graph debugger

returns: "Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped."

note: after some time it seems like facebook crawler does crawl my site (takes days for facebook to crawl my site) and then everything is fine. (but still new posts having the problem mentioned above)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you fixed your issue, but I have just had the same trouble with our blog, and noticed it was only showing in posts that had external url links to images!

All local hosted images didn't show the FB crawl issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

Basically the this issue can be a cuase of DNS or server problems, 
so all you need to do is to force facebook to scrape your website agian.

so you need to pass "scrape=true" like so:

```
POST /?id={object-instance-id or object-url}&scrape=true
FB.api(
            "POST /?id={<%=ogURL.Content%>}&scrape=true",
            function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error) {
                    do something
                }
            }
        );
```

this worked for me, I hope it helps who ever encounter the same problem.